# Problem of dashed stroke in illustrator between 2 characters ,when writing in Arabic font

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, fonts, arabic

I have problem of dashed stroke in illustrator between 2 characters ,just when writing in Arabic font like this picture.
[image: Dashed Stroke]

Comment: Hello! welcome to GDSE. at first it seems that font itself having a space between two characters although in arabic typeface I've seen that there is no space; so basically you can overwrite the spacing from character panel. just reduce spacing to -20 from 0 in your case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about Arabic fonts, however Roman curvise/script fonts which also have joined letters also experience a similar problem when the letters join or overlap.

This solution is for Adobe Illustrator.

The first example below shows what happens when you try to apply a stroke to individual letters in the appearance panel. This is similar to your Arabic example.

The second shows what happens when you click and drag the stroke under the characters in the appearance panel.  A slightly thicker stroke is required since half of the stroke will be hidden under the character fill.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Character Panel, set the kerning between characters from optical to metric.
Worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Keming is the wrong kerning (since r and n flow into eachother :)